# Porting from `only/except`: How to run a gitlab-ci job only for tags excluding a pattern with `rules` in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to convert a `.gitlab-ci.yml` job from the deprecated [`only/except`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#only--except) pattern to [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#rules), specifically I want to run a job only if it's for a tag but not if that tag starts with `config-`.

Currently we use this, which at least works<sup>1</sup>.

```yaml
build_image:
  stage: build_image
  only:
  - tags
  except:
  - /^config-.*$/
```

I have tried the `rules` based approach as follows, but that runs for every tag, including `config`:

```yaml
build_image:
  stage: build_image
  rules:
    # only tags, except config
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^config-.*$/'
      when: never
    - when: never
```

Additionally I tried to use negative lookahead regex - without success, since gitlab's ci linter screams *jobs:build_image:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax*.

```yaml
build_image:
  stage: build_image
  rules:
    # only tags, except config (using negative lookahead)
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^(?!config-).*$/'
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```

So how can I trigger a job only for tags excluding a pattern with the new `rules` based approach?

1: apart from not being able to be combined with other rules later on

Answer (score 2):

This rules worked for me (with Gitlab 13.12) :

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && $CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^config-.*$/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to combine the [unlike operator `!~`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#regex-pattern-matching) with the regular tag check `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`:

```yaml
build_image:
  stage: build_image
  rules:
    # only tags and only those not starting with config-
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG && ($CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^config-.*$/ )'
      when: on_success
    - when: never
```